# JQ Add key/value to json object in order to enumerate the objects

Tags: json, range, jq, key-value

I have a list of objects (20 in total) and I need to insert a new key-value pair with the positional number  of each object (values in range 1 to 20).
I have managed to put together this code, however I end up replicating the objects inside of the array so instead of 20 objects I end up with about 100.

```
jq "(.data.items, .data.primaryItemResultList.items)| values | length as $l | values[] += {ranking: range(1, $l)}| .[]"
```

When I ty to add a static value to the "ranking" it works correctly, however if I use the range function it doesn't produce the desired output as mentioned before.

Here is an example of the shortened code:

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "items_10244-20964274",
        "size": "80 ct",
        "productId": "20964274",
        "brandName": "peets",
        "brandId": "25555",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-17284948",
        "size": "75 ct",
        "productId": "17284948",
        "legacyId": "2991007854",
        "brandName": "peet's",
        "brandId": "50954",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-19232655",
        "size": "3 lb",
        "productId": "19232655",
        "brandName": "kirkland signature",
        "brandId": "7632",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would anyone be able to help with this issue and identify the mistake?

The expected output is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "items_10244-20964274",
        "size": "80 ct",
        "productId": "20964274",
        "brandName": "peets",
        "brandId": "25555",
        "ranking": 1,
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-17284948",
        "size": "75 ct",
        "productId": "17284948",
        "legacyId": "2991007854",
        "brandName": "peet's",
        "brandId": "50954",
        "ranking": 2,
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-19232655",
        "size": "3 lb",
        "productId": "19232655",
        "brandName": "kirkland signature",
        "brandId": "7632",
        "ranking": 3,
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exploit the circumstance that `to_entries`, when applied to an array, will use the (0-based) item index as `.key`. Add `+1` to make it 1-based.

```bash
.data.items |= [to_entries[] | .value + {ranking: (.key+1)}]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D9okFNCRb8K)

For an approach based on `range(length)`, I'd use `transpose` to zip the items array with the indices array:

```bash
.data.items |= ([., [range(length)+1]] | transpose | map(.[0] + {ranking: .[1]}))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/T5HpxDITlbn)

Output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "items_10244-20964274",
        "size": "80 ct",
        "productId": "20964274",
        "brandName": "peets",
        "brandId": "25555",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
        "ranking": 1
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-17284948",
        "size": "75 ct",
        "productId": "17284948",
        "legacyId": "2991007854",
        "brandName": "peet's",
        "brandId": "50954",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
        "ranking": 2
      },
      {
        "id": "items_10244-19232655",
        "size": "3 lb",
        "productId": "19232655",
        "brandName": "kirkland signature",
        "brandId": "7632",
        "retailer": {
          "isUltrafast": false,
          "__typename": "RetailersRetailer"
        },
        "ranking": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: JSON does not support or recognize the ordering of object fields. Thus, the actual position of the new `ranking` field makes no structural difference. You can, however, tweak jq into changing the textual representation it generates for output. For  instance, to move the `retailer` field to last position, remove it and add it again with `del(.retailer) + {retailer}` (See demos for the [to_entries](https://jqplay.org/s/HOKxtm0hpqD) and the [range/transpose](https://jqplay.org/s/vTrggRk4ZZl) approaches). But keep in mind that this modification is only aesthetical. Any JSON post-processor may disregard this ordering again.